# ERROR：Could not find the colcon-terminal-notifier.app in the install prefix '/usr/local

Tags: ros2, colcon

ERROR：Could not find the colcon-terminal-notifier.app in the install prefix '/usr/local

Operation OS: MacOS Monterey
ROS2 Version:Foxy

When I use the command "colcon build",The terminal post the Error:

ERROR:colcon.colcon_notification.desktop_notification.terminal_notifier:Could not find the colcon-terminal-notifier.app in the install prefix '/usr/local'

Can you help me how can I solve this error? Thank you！

The colcon path is

colcon: /usr/local/bin/colcon

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with the [colcon-notification library](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-notification) which has been reported [in this pull request](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-notification/pull/66).

Until it is fixed in the library, you can work around this by manually making the change in your copy of the `colcon_notification` python library:

- Find the `site_packages` directory used by your ROS2 installation, probably somewhere like `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages`.
- Edit the file `colcon_notification/desktop_notification/terminal_notifier.py`.
- Make the edits on line 100 [as shown in the pull request](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-notification/pull/66/files):

```
-       'colcon_terminal_notifier.app'
+       'colcon-terminal-notifier.app'
```

As you can see, the fix is simply just changing the filename of the notifier app in the script from using underscores to dashes.

Answer (score 0):

The Matt's answer shed light on my issue, but couldn't find the colcon_notification from the site-packages folder.

I was able to solve this issue by [building the colcon source code manually](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/developer/bootstrap.html) and run 'colcon build' again in the installation folder.